# Checking if the viewer came from a certain site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to check if the website viewer came from a certain link. First, I tried doing this in two programming languages.

```
window.onload = function () {
 alert(document.referrer);
}
```

Here, in JavaScript, just a blank alert pops up. The alert does not have any data.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

As you can see, I tried doing it in PHP too, but I get an error this time.

*Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /blahblahblah/blahblahblah/public_html/done.php on line 79*

Does anyone know a fix or something?

Comment: The sender is not obliged to populate the referer field. If they don't, there's not much you can do about it. It's completely optional, and even when it's populated there's no guarantee its accurate

Comment: If that's the case, is it possible to tell if they came from a certain website in a different way? I'm trying to integrate this with linkvertise.

Comment: It's not a topic I'm very familiar with specifically, but I believe people use techniques related to cookies, or querystring variables, or little scripts in their pages. Advertising and analytics and afilliates etc is big business and very sophisticated in terms of technology - that much I do know. It's probably something you need to spend some time researching properly to start with, rather than asking one-off questions here. Maybe the people who run this linkvertise service also have some advice, or some documentation you can work with.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your advice. I'm about to start researching into a different method. Thanks for your help.